# Ubuntu 14.04 + fglrx + MSI Radeon R9 390x Kernel Panic

Tags: kernel, radeon, fglrx

Getting a kernel panic whenever I try to use my new MSI r9 390x.

```
[ 2722.396297] AMD IOMMUv2 driver by Joerg Roedel <joerg.roedel@amd.com>
[ 2722.396299] AMD IOMMUv2 functionality not available on this system
[ 2722.398736] fglrx: module license 'Proprietary. (C) 2002 - ATI Technologies, Starnberg, GERMANY' taints kernel.
[ 2722.398738] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
[ 2722.404609] <6>[fglrx] Maximum main memory to use for locked dma buffers: 31212 MBytes.
[ 2722.404718] <6>[fglrx]   vendor: 1002 device: 67b0 revision: 80 count: 1
[ 2722.405604] <6>[fglrx] ioport: bar 4, base 0xe000, size: 0x100
[ 2722.405699] <6>[fglrx] Kernel PAT support is enabled
[ 2722.405708] <6>[fglrx] module loaded - fglrx 15.20.3 [Sep  8 2015] with 1 minors
[ 2734.204240] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[ 2734.204244] WARNING: CPU: 3 PID: 10497 at /build/linux-zODV55/linux-3.13.0/drivers/pci/msi.c:882 pci_enable_msi_block+0x2db/0x2f0()
[ 2734.204245] Modules linked in: fglrx(POX) amd_iommu_v2 xt_nat pci_stub vboxpci(OX) vboxnetadp(OX) vboxnetflt(OX) vboxdrv(OX) ipt_MASQUERADE iptable_nat nf_nat_ipv4 nf_nat nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4    xt_conntrack nf_conntrack ipt_REJECT xt_CHECKSUM iptable_mangle xt_tcpudp bridge stp llc ip6table_filter ip6_tables iptable_filter ip_tables ebtable_nat ebtables x_tables snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek rfcomm    bnep bluetooth nfsd auth_rpcgss nfs_acl nfs lockd sunrpc binfmt_misc fscache intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm eeepc_wmi snd_hda_intel asus_wmi snd_hda_codec sparse_keymap mxm_wmi    radeon snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_page_alloc crct10dif_pclmul dm_multipath crc32_pclmul snd_seq_midi scsi_dh snd_seq_midi_event i915 snd_rawmidi aesni_intel aes_x86_64 snd_seq lrw ttm snd_seq_device gf128mul drm_kms_helper    snd_timer glue_helper ablk_helper snd cryptd drm soundcore mei_me mei i2c_algo_bit serio_raw shpchp lpc_ich lp wmi mac_hid video parport e1000e ptp ahci psmouse libahci pps_core
[ 2734.204275] CPU: 3 PID: 10497 Comm: ethminer Tainted: P           OX 3.13.0-86-generic #131-Ubuntu
[ 2734.204276] Hardware name: System manufacturer System Product Name/SABERTOOTH Z77, BIOS 1805 12/19/2012
[ 2734.204277]  0000000000000000 ffff8807ee7559d8 ffffffff8172a394 0000000000000000
[ 2734.204279]  0000000000000009 ffff8807ee755a10 ffffffff810699bd ffff880803f99000
[ 2734.204281]  0000000000000000 ffff8807ee755ad0 0000000000000001 ffff8807ff1d4f10
[ 2734.204282] Call Trace:
[ 2734.204286]  [<ffffffff8172a394>] dump_stack+0x64/0x82
[ 2734.204288]  [<ffffffff810699bd>] warn_slowpath_common+0x7d/0xa0
[ 2734.204289]  [<ffffffff81069a9a>] warn_slowpath_null+0x1a/0x20
[ 2734.204291]  [<ffffffff813caabb>] pci_enable_msi_block+0x2db/0x2f0
[ 2734.204344]  [<ffffffffa09616e3>] KCL_RequestMSI+0x13/0x20 [fglrx]
[ 2734.204380]  [<ffffffffa0984faf>] IRQMGR_initialize+0x24f/0x390 [fglrx]
[ 2734.204415]  [<ffffffffa0984d07>] ? IRQMGR_alloc_context+0xb7/0x110 [fglrx]
[ 2734.204450]  [<ffffffffa09835c2>] ? irqmgr_wrap_initialize+0x22/0xc0 [fglrx]
[ 2734.204484]  [<ffffffffa0984af3>] ? firegl_irqmgr_init+0x53/0x100 [fglrx]
[ 2734.204519]  [<ffffffffa0995dd1>] ? hal_init_gpu+0x221/0x4d0 [fglrx]
[ 2734.204552]  [<ffffffffa096f2fe>] ? firegl_open+0x2de/0x310 [fglrx]
[ 2734.204583]  [<ffffffffa095d1a7>] ? ip_firegl_open+0x17/0x20 [fglrx]
[ 2734.204613]  [<ffffffffa095e9e8>] ? firegl_stub_open+0x98/0x100 [fglrx]
[ 2734.204616]  [<ffffffff811c5fef>] ? chrdev_open+0x9f/0x1d0
[ 2734.204617]  [<ffffffff811beaf3>] ? do_dentry_open+0x233/0x2e0
[ 2734.204619]  [<ffffffff811c5f50>] ? cdev_put+0x30/0x30
[ 2734.204620]  [<ffffffff811bee29>] ? vfs_open+0x49/0x50
[ 2734.204623]  [<ffffffff811d0412>] ? do_last+0x562/0x1370
[ 2734.204625]  [<ffffffff811d12db>] ? path_openat+0xbb/0x670
[ 2734.204627]  [<ffffffff811d26fa>] ? do_filp_open+0x3a/0x90
[ 2734.204628]  [<ffffffff811df547>] ? __alloc_fd+0xa7/0x130
[ 2734.204630]  [<ffffffff811c0959>] ? do_sys_open+0x129/0x2a0
[ 2734.204632]  [<ffffffff811c0aee>] ? SyS_open+0x1e/0x20
[ 2734.204634]  [<ffffffff8173b01d>] ? system_call_fastpath+0x1a/0x1f
[ 2734.204635] ---[ end trace 2532da5ce22d6c08 ]---
[ 2734.204652] radeon 0000:01:00.0: irq 59 for MSI/MSI-X
[ 2734.204661] radeon 0000:01:00.0: irq 60 for MSI/MSI-X
[ 2734.204665] ------------[ cut here ]------------
```

Any ideas?